# Proof with list in Coq

Tags: list, math, coq

I'm trying to proof something in CoqIDE (for school). I'm blocking on a step, here is the

```
`Print length. (* la longueur de listes *)


Lemma mystere A:  forall l : list A, length l = 0 <-> l = nil.
intros.
destruct l.
* split.
- intros.
reflexivity.
- intros. 
simpl.
reflexivity.
* split.
- intros.
???? <- I have tried many things, but without success..
Admitted.
`
```

Thanks guys for your consideration !

Comment: You should be able to derive a contradiction from `S (length l) = 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your context has a hypothesis

```
H : length (a :: l) = 0
```

This is absurd, because `length (a :: l)` is a successor.  You can see this by running `simpl in *` or `simpl in H`, which results in

```
H : S (length l) = 0
```

If you now run

```
Search (S _) 0.
```

the second entry (after `H`) is

```
O_S: forall n : nat, 0 <> S n
```

So we can run `symmetry in H` to get a hypothesis that matches better with `O_S`.

```
H : 0 = S (length l)
```

Since `a <> b` is just `a = b -> False`, we can now run `apply O_S in H` to get

```
H : False
```

And now we are effectively done.  We can finish the proof with `exfalso; assumption`, or with `exfalso; exact H`, or with `easy`, or with `now trivial` (or `now idtac`), or with `case H`, or with `destruct H`, or with `elim H`, or with `refine match H with end`, or with `induction H`, or with `refine (False_rect _ H)`, or `tauto`.  All of these basically amount to the same thing (although some of them, like `easy` and `tauto`, can also solve other goals).

Comment: Thanks Jason for this answer, and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I think change your Lemma like so,

```
Definition length_nil_list (l: nat): bool :=
match l with
| O => true
| S _ => false
end.

Compute length_nil_list (S O).
Compute length_nil_list (O).
Compute length_nil_list (S (S O)).

Definition list_nil {X : Type} (l: list X): bool:=
match l with
| nil => true
| cons h t => false
end.

Compute list_nil [].
Compute list_nil [0].
Compute list_nil nil.

Lemma mystere A:  forall l : list A, 
length_nil_list (length l) = true <-> list_nil l = true.
Proof.
intros.
destruct l.
* split.
- intros.
reflexivity.
- intros. 
simpl.
reflexivity.
* split. 
- simpl. auto.
- simpl in *. auto.
Qed.
```